# Call Postgres procedure with Composite param in .net 6

Tags: postgresql, ado.net, .net-6.0, npgsql

I have created a custom type in postgres as composite and I am passing it to a procedure as a parameter, I want to call the procedure from .net 6 but I keep getting the error `"InvalidCastException: Can't convert .NET type 'ArtProductService.Models.Dtos.BulkUpdateAcquisitionDto' to PostgreSQL '.<unknown>' within an array"`

this is my function

```
  var dataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(_connectionString);
  dataSourceBuilder.MapComposite<List<myObject>>("composite[]");
  await using var dataSource = dataSourceBuilder.Build();
  using var conn = dataSource.CreateConnection();
  conn.ConnectionString = _connectionString;

  string query = "\"schema\".\"procedureName\"";
  conn.Open();
  NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);

  var param = command.CreateParameter();
  param.ParameterName = "paramName";

  param.Value = paramValue;
  param.DataTypeName = "composite[]";

  command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  command.Parameters.Add(param);
  await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
dataSourceBuilder.MapComposite<List<myObject>>("composite[]");
```

The array itself (or List) is not a composite object; try mapping the base type:

```cs
dataSourceBuilder.MapComposite<myObject>("composite");
```

The array mapping will automatically be done as well by Npgsql when you do the above.

(Also make sure that you really want your PG type is actually called `composite` - that's a pretty bad name for a type).

If that doesn't help, please post a fully runnable code sample above rather than a snippet.